# Determining Series Convergence without the Weierstrass $M-$Test

Tags: real-analysis

I have finished all of the other questions and examples set using the Weierstrass $M-$Test, however this one is proving to be tricky:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx-1}{{n^{2}}}$$

over the interval $[2,5]$.

I found that any series that has a modulus equal to or larger than this one does not converge and so couldn't conclude uniform convergence via the $M-$Test.
But I know that this doesn't prove that it doesn't converge uniformly, just that I need to investigate further and that's where I am stuck.

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If that series converges, then so does

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{nx-1}{{n^{2}}}+\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

If you break apart the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx-1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$$

By the P-series test for convergence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent, however the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n}=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is $x$ times the harmonic series which diverges. Therefore the original series is divergent.

Comment: I thought it would be divergent, I just needed a strict way of showing it. Thank you for the clarification